# Octave: Remove the frame (`box` function) with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, octave

When using `gnuplot` in `Octave`, I cannot remove the frame of the plot (border lines). Usually, `box off` does the trick, but with gnuplot only the ticks on the upper and right borders disappear, but the lines themselves remain. It works fine with `fltk` and `qt`

Here is an illustration of the problem, using

```
graphics_toolkit gnuplot
%graphics_toolkit qt
hist(rand(1,1000))
box off
%box on
```

[image: Box on or off in different graphics toolkits]

I tried the longer way of `hax=gca; set(hax,'Box','off')` with the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. 
Reproduced in octave-3.8.2 and octave-4.0.0-rc3.

This seems closely related to an [older thread](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/change-position-of-x-axis-td3893956.html), where the `unset border` gnuplot command was not issued.

And indeed after

```
graphics_toolkit gnuplot
hist(rand(1,1000))
box off
drawnow ("png", "debug.png", false, "debug.gp")
```

there are multiple `border` commands in the debug.gp file.

[Search on the bug tracker](https://savannah.gnu.org/search/?Search=Search&words=box+off&type_of_search=bugs&only_group_id=1925&exact=1&max_rows=25#options) shows that this has not been reported yet.
Please [file a bug report](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=octave), with a link to your question.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I filed a [bug report](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?44871) as you kindly suggested.